# Convert EmguCV image to system drawing bitmap

Tags: c#, winforms, emgucv

I am writing a c# program with emgucv library.
I use the imagebox in emgucv to capture image from webcam.
And I want to get the color pixel of the image by using bitmap.Getpixel() by mouse clicking the imagebox.
However,
it contain error The error is..it cannot implicitly convert type 'Emgu.CV.IImage' to 'System.Drawing.Bitmap'

Can anyone give me idea to solve this problem?

```
      Bitmap bitmap = newdetectimageBox.Image; //error
```

Comment: `ToBitmap()` and `Bitmap` are missing from EmguCV v4.4.0.4099|4077 so I'm using v4.3.0.3890 instead for now and it's working fine

Comment: @axon, they are not missing but moved. https://www.nuget.org/packages/Emgu.CV.Bitmap/

Answer (score 6):

Please use this code

```
 Image<Bgr, Byte> ImageFrame = newdetectimageBox.Image ; //Capture the cam Image 
 Bitmap BmpInput = ImageFrame.ToBitmap(); //Convert the emgu Image to BitmapImage
```

Comment: from documentation: // Remarks:
        //     For better performance on Image<Gray, Byte> and Image<Bgr, Byte>, consider using
        //     the Bitmap property

Answer (score 2):

Here's how you do it (image data is NOT shared with the bitmap) - see documentation on emgu website about [IImage](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/2.4.2/document/Index.html) :

```
Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(newdetectimageBox.Image.Bitmap);
```

Answer (score 1):

The IImage interface contains property Bitmap.

However if you are using the Image class than you should maybe use the ToBitmap method.